# Sign in to Google Drive using API and create spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I made a website that can show data sorting as a table so I have a function that help users download the table as a CSV file(using PHP). But I wanna make a function that users can sign in to own Google Drive account and upload the table instead of download as a CSV file.

- Can you guys advising me how to do it? (Using PHP)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [**Google APIs Client Library for PHP**](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) (beta). The examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples#Drive_API) can probably get you started.